HTML email not centered in most Outlook app(based on email test results)
I am currently in the process of cleaning my email template code and just found out that the  tag and align=center element were already obsolete. What are the other ways to fix this in Outlook? Thanks!
I used margin:auto; to fix the issue. The email looked good on the browser as well as in Gmail when I sent a test. However, I just noticed an issue with Outlook apps when I checked Email on Acid, most of them are not centered on Outlook as it is aligned to the left.

Please show the relevant code. Also https://www.caniemail.com/ might help - check every CSS property.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with an emphasis on the minimal. Then put just enough code into your question to demonstrate the problem. Please edit the question, not put stuff into answers. Thanks.
